# How do I use the mail manager without the $to value?

Tags: 8, emails

I want to send an email for multiple users without a *to* address. Setting `$to` `NULL`, and empty string `'undisclosed-recipients:;'` doesn't work.

How can I send an email with just BCC recipients?

Comment: If `'undisclosed-recipients:;'` doesn't work, then this most likely is not supported by your webhost's MTA.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you avoid this approach as messages with lots of recipients in the bcc field are more likely to trigger spam filters on the receiving mail server.

I would loop through each email address and send them a separate email instead, if there are a lot of emails to send then consider moving them into a batch operation.